# Unable to find debug symbols for Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel 5.4.13

Tags: 18.04, apt, kernel, debug

I am trying to get the debug symbols for Ubuntu 18.04 bionic, kernel 5.4.13.

I followed the below steps:

```
uname -r              # 5.4.13
uname -v              # #1 SMP Sun Jan 26 17:18:26 UTC 2020
apt-get update
apt-get install lsb-release
lsb_release -c        # bionic
apt-get install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
```

Added the following lines to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list:

```
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then ran:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-5.4.13-dbgsym
```

This command always fails saying:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-5.4.13-dbgsym
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-5.4.13-dbgsym'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-5.4.13-dbgsym'
```

Please can I get help with this.

Comment: The debug symbols don't seem to be there. What makes you sure that they should be? Is there a specific guide you are following?

Comment: There are several blogs which say the same thing - https://gist.github.com/NLKNguyen/2fd920e2a50fd4b9701f

Comment: Another tutorial with similar instructions - https://hadibrais.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/installing-ubuntu-kernel-debugging-symbols/